# How can we use a constraint to ensure that no values of an array are NULL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    arr_column VARCHAR[] NOT NULL
)
```

This does not prevent values of the array being set to NULL when a row is inserted. So, I would like a constraint to enforce this rule. My attempt is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    arr_column VARCHAR[] NOT NULL 
        CHECK (NOT (ARRAY[NULL]::VARCHAR[] <@ arr_column))
)
```

But unfortunately, this does not fail if I insert:

```
INSERT INTO test (ARRAY['some_string', NULL]::VARCHAR[])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One easy and straightforward way to do such a check is using triggers, but you can also simply create a function and use it at the `CHECK` clause as you've been doing so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_null_element(arr TEXT[]) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $BODY$
DECLARE j INT;
BEGIN
  FOR j IN 1 .. ARRAY_UPPER(arr, 1) LOOP
    IF arr[j] IS NULL THEN
       RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
RETURN TRUE;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So when creating your table you just need:

```
CREATE temp TABLE test (
    arr_column VARCHAR[] NOT NULL 
        CHECK (check_null_element(arr_column))
);
```

Trying to insert an array with `NULL` values:

```
db=# INSERT INTO test VALUES (ARRAY['some_string', NULL]::VARCHAR[]);
FEHLER:  neue Zeile für Relation »test« verletzt Check-Constraint »test_arr_column_check«
DETAIL:  Fehlgeschlagene Zeile enthält ({some_string,NULL}).
```

And with a *valid* one ..

```
db=# INSERT INTO test VALUES (ARRAY['some_string', 'NOT NULL :-)']::VARCHAR[]);
INSERT 0 1
```

**EDIT:** Nice to have:

To avoid unwanted exceptions, you can additionally check if the parameter itself is `NULL` - redundant for this question, since it's been already checked with a `NOT NULL` constraint at the `CREATE TABLE` statement. This can be done by adding the following condition to the function: `IF arr IS NULL THEN RETURN FALSE; END IF;`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_null_element(arr TEXT[]) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $BODY$
DECLARE j INT;
BEGIN
  IF arr IS NULL THEN RETURN FALSE; END IF;
  FOR j IN 1 .. ARRAY_UPPER(arr, 1) LOOP
    IF arr[j] IS NULL THEN
       RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
RETURN TRUE;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: A minor performance improvement: you can leave the loop immediately if you find the first NULL. There is no need to test all remaining elements as well. You could replace `res := false;` with `return false;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're absolutely right. I'll edit my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to do the trick, with very little code:

```
CHECK (array_position(arr_column, NULL) is NULL)
```